# CSS animate width from 0px to inline css defined % value

Tags: css, css-animations

Is there a way with pure CSS without javascript to animate element's width to server generated value? Let's say I have this div:

```
<div class="bar" style="width:{$value}%;"></div>
```

I would like it to animate from 0 to `$value` that is set by PHP on page render. So initial state forced by animation would be `width: 0px` and the final would be `width: {$value}%;`

Comment: Are you using `PHP`?

Comment: Yup. Using PHP to determine $value

Comment: You want the transition while rendering?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A working solution using animation:

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tw3u7L3a/1/)

```
<div class="bar" style="width:80%;"></div> <!-- where 80% is the PHP value-->
```

```
.bar{
  background: lime;
  padding: 30px 0;
  animation: test 2s;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {width: 0;}
}
```